# How to update the key of a json object?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have this json format in my database jsonb column

```
[
   {
      "firstName": "John", 
      "lastName": "Doe"
   }
]
```

and I want to update the key "firstName", how to do that?

So far I have this query:

```
UPDATE person
SET 
    field = jsonb_set(
    field::jsonb, 
    concat('{0,firstName}')::text[], 
    '"newFirstName"'::jsonb)
```

but the query above updates the value instead of the key.. how can I update just the key?

Comment: Why are you storing that in an array if you only have one element? And what if the array has multiple objects? Do you want to replace the key for all of them, or just the first one?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is project-specific and the tool I'm using can only read it in that way. The array will only have one object with multiple elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the element without the `firstName` key, append the new key/value and then put it back into the array:

```
update person
  set field = jsonb_set(field, 
                        '{0}', 
                        ((field -> 0) - 'firstName')||jsonb_build_object('newFirstName', field -> 0 -> 'firstName'));
```

`(field -> 0) - 'firstName')` returns the first element without the firstname key.

Then `jsonb_build_object('newFirstName', field -> 0 -> 'firstName')` builds a new key/value pair with the new keyname, but the existing value of `firstName` and this is appended to the result of the first expression using `||`

The result of the above is then put into the first array element using `jsonb_set()`

---

Online example: https://rextester.com/YPF75074